# How to commit changes through reference from vector into that vector in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, stdvector, lvalue

Having this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A{
   std::vector<std::string> vec;
public:
    std::string &save(std::string const&s){
        vec.push_back(s);
        return vec.back();
    }
    std::vector<std::string> const& getVec() const {
        return vec;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    std::string str = a.save("abc");
    str[str.length() - 1] = 'd';

    std::cout << str << '\n';
    std::cout << a.getVec()[0] << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
abd
abc
```

expecting:

```
abd 
abd
```

I would expect that since the `A::save` returns a reference to the last element of the vector, the changes made into that element would be commit into vector as well (becuase of that reference). But it apparently does not. Why?

Comment: `std::string str` is a copy. `std::string& str = a.save("abc");`.

Answer (score 2):

When you wrote:

```
std::string str = a.save("abc");
```

The above statement creates a variable named `str` of type `std::string` and has a **copy** of the `std::string`(which was returned by reference) returned by the call expression `a.save("abc")`. That is, `str` is a copy of the element in the `std::vector` data member `vec`.

To get your desired output change the statement to as shown below:

```
std::string& str = a.save("abc");
```

Now, in the above statement, `str` is an alias for the `std::string` that was returned(by reference) by the call expression `a.save("abc")`.